# Google Maps API not serving up the latest release version

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Two days ago the released version of the google maps API was updated to 3.19

Version 3.18 broke some things in our application so we had been explicitly asking for 3.17 until it was deprecated. We updated the application to work with 3.19 and ask for the latest release version, instead of explicitly specifying the version.

Yesterday it went back to 3.18.20, which again broke our application.

We have since updated to explicitly request 3.19, but I'm wondering why the default version is now returning 3.18 instead of the current release version?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the version number the version you get will vary according to [the documentation on versioning](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning):

You can indicate which version of the API to load within your application by specifying it using the v parameter of the Maps Javascript API bootstrap request. Three options are supported:

- The experimental version, specified with v=3.exp.
- The release version, specified with v=3
- The frozen version, specified with v=3.0

If you do not explicitly specify a version, you will receive the experimental version by default. Google Maps API for Work customers who specify a client ID will receive the release version by default.

If you specify a specific version (i.e. v=3.18), you will get that version while it is available.  Once it is retired, you will get the frozen version.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue, and submitted a bug to Google. See their answer here:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7694

To reiterate their answer, there were apparently some issues with 3.19, so they reverted their experimental/release/frozen versions. I've chosen to directly use 3.19, as it doesn't seem to introduce any issues for my purposes.

Comment: Per the Google Maps team, this has been resolved as of today. See the bug report linked above.